# Parsing JSON Data from URL with Android Studio

Tags: json, android-studio

I'm trying to parse JSON data from URL and show the data in my app.
JSON Example (After accessing specific URL):

```
[{"placeID":"1","placeName":"Test Place","city":"New York","type":"Rest"..
```

How I can read this data and show a list of the places recieved from the API?

I've been trying ALL of the guides over the internet for parsing JSON data from URL with Android Studio and without. As a total beginner with Android developement, I couldn't make one working exmaple with json even when the author shared the final example for download. I hope you can help me in noob-friendly way and step by step or refer me to the right places.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Android uses `org.json` as the JSON library, in which case something like this works to retrieve information about each place (assuming `data` is a valid JSON string)

```
try {
    String data = "\"[{\"placeID\":\"1\",\"placeName\":\"Test Place\",\"city\":\"New York\",\"type\":\"Rest\"..";
    JSONArray places = new JSONArray(data);
    for (int i = 0; i < places.length(); i++)
        JSONObject place = (JSONObject) places.get(i);

        int id = place.getInt("id");
        String name = place.getString("placeName");
        String city = place.getString("city");
        // etc...
        // Do what you wish with the id, name, city and other variables.
        // It loops through here for each item in the JSON variable.
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This goes through each place in the JSON array and grabs some of the variables from it. It would probably be smart to create a data class and call it something like `Place`. You could then pass in the data with a constructor: `new Place(id, name, city);` (see this constructor for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22419370/5236779).

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's totally not noob friendly help, I have no idea where to place it and it doesn't help much since I need to read from URL.

Comment: I guess I assumed you had the internet connection figured out and were wondering how to parse hence the title. I'd say StackOverflow isn't the best place to post a solution for this because you need several different parts, but to be brief: (1) Give the app permission to use internet (android manifest), (2) In your activity (MainActivity) onCreate or where you want it, get a page's contents (3) Parse it with the code above and (4) Display it, a simple Toast.createToast works to start off.

Comment: I know it's totally not noob friendly, but it's not usually something someone new would dive into. Try to accomplish each part, bit by bit?

Comment: Now it's better, since you let me know about every part from scratch. Thanks